# Computed is not assignable to Observable after upgrade to Knockout.js 3.5.0

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

Knockout.js 3.5.0 comes with it's own type definitions on npm.
Let's have this variable `x` defined as:

```
const x: ko.Observable<boolean> = ko.computed(() => true);
```

Now we got compiler error: 
*Type 'Computed' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': valueHasMutated, valueWillMutate*.

I understand what compiler is trying to tell me, but I think that principally this is wrong - because every computed is also an observable. This behaviour worked well on 3.4.x using type definitions from @types/knockout.

There is the `Subscribable` type, which I believe is some "parent" type, and it works in declaration:

```
const x: ko.Subscribable<boolean> = ko.computed(() => true);
```

This throws no error. However no type checking is performed on value setter:

```
x(2);    // this is wrong but no compiler error
```

Can anybody shed some light on these new type hierarchy changes and how should we use it?

Comment: Isn't there a `computed` or `dependantObservable` type you assign to `x`? I'm not entirely sure if "every computed is also an observable" is technically correct. Like you mention, I think the prototype for a `computed` is the `subscribable`, not the `observable`.

Comment: In KO 3.4 with that "old" typing we sucessfully used `Observable` type as "mother" type for all "more complicated" types like `Computed`. This idea can be somehow derived from knockout documentation for util function, that states: _ko.isObservable - returns true for observables, observable arrays, and all computed observables._. In new typings I can clearly see that `Subscribable` is parent for `Observable` and `Computed`, with no direct relation between its childs. It's somewhat sad that type system changed, but OK, we will adapt as always...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going through the upgrade to 3.5.0 myself right now. It is a big change since we should be using the type file that comes with the project and that changes all the names of the classes and gets rid of the global ko. I think these are all good things. I have been happy with the transformation of my code (well, except for trying to get knockout-validation to compile).

I ran into the exact issue you are running into. I knew that when I had assigned a computed to an observable typed variable that it was a hack, but I also knew it would work just fine because the interface was close enough. This upgrade forced me to revisit the hack and to deal with it properly. Here is how I do it now in my code:

I know define the variable as one that takes either an observable or a computed:

```
class SomeClass {
   public value: Observable<boolean> | Computed<boolean>;
}
```

This allows all the other developers who might be reading the code that value might be a computed so they shouldn't just blindly assign a value to it.

Comment: It is exactly what works as expected, including type checking. But IMHO `Subscribable` type should work as well, because as I understand it `ko.Observable<boolean> | ko.Computed<boolean>` in fact equals `ko.Subscribable<boolean>`, at least in any practical way. But looking into d.ts file it seems that maybe some extenders spoils this. Did not tested it. Anyway, for now this type union seems like the "right way to do it", thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add in your compiler options

```
"path" {
   ...
   "knockout": [ "node_modules/@types/knockout" ],
   ...
}
```

that way you can use old KO typings until better way to upgrade code would be found

Answer (score 1):

In Knockout 3.5.1, I was able to reference the interface `PureComputed` defined in the Knockout package:

```js
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import { Computed, PureComputed, Observable } from 'knockout';

class MyClass
  originalComments: string;
  comments: Observable<string>;

  constructor(serverData: any) {
    this.originalComments = serverData.comments || '';
    this.comments = ko.observable(this.originalComments);
  }

  hasChanged: PureComputed<boolean> = ko.pureComputed(() => this.comments() !==  this.originalComments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KnockoutComputed<T>` like this:

```
const x: KnockoutComputed<boolean> = ko.computed(() => true);
```

Comment: Thanx, but KnockoutComputed type comes from `@types/knockout` definition, which are for v3.4. However v3.5 on npm has it's own definitions, which are "organized" differently. I am seeking help with "new" type system, because in v3.4 type system it was perfectly OK to do `const x: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.computed(() => true);`, which was great and supports idea that observable is supertype of all other complicated variants (like computed one)

Comment: @TomHANAX But `@types/knockout` latest version is `3.4.64`
according to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/knockout

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of an Observable and a Computed as work-around.

```
InEditMode: Observable<boolean> = ko.observable(false);
InEditModeComputed: Computed<void> = ko.computed(() => {
    const result = this.ComposeMode() === EComposeMode.Edit && !this.SaveConsultatieInProgress();
    this.InEditMode(result);
});
```